# What is the meaning of "e" in this timing diagram?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation

https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Edgecapture

[image]

What is the meaning of "e" in this timing diagram?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`e` is a numeric value displayed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) format.  It is the same as 14 in decimal.  It means that bits `in[3:1]` are set to 1, and the other 29 bits of `in` are 0.

It is common for Verilog simulation waveform viewers to display bus signals (like the 32-bit `in` signal) in hex format, also in shortest form (no prefix, no leading 0's).  For example, `e` represents the 32-bit value in Verilog syntax:

```
32'h0000_000e
```

Answer (score 5):

toolic is correct; this is simply `0x0000000E`.

The important part of the description is the following:

> The output bit should be set (to 1) the cycle after an 1 to 0 transition occurs *(on the input vector)*.

(italics added by me)

When input goes from `0x0` to `0x2` (`0b0000` to `0b0010`), this change only consists of transitions from 0 to 1, and therefore the output does not change. Once the input goes from `0x2` to `0xE` (`0b0010` to `0b1110`) there are still only 0-to-1 transitions and the output does not change.

Finally, the input changes from `0xE` to `0x0` (`0b1110` to `0b0000`) which involves three bits changing from 1 to 0. The module sets those three bits on the output vector to 1, resulting in an output of `0xE` / `0b1110`.

The remainder of the diagram shows the synchronous reset: if the reset is high at a rising edge, the output immediately goes zero at that time. However, since the input went from 2 to 0 at that same rising edge, but

> the 'reset' event occurs one cycle earlier than the 'set' event, so there is no conflict here.

---

If, instead of a transition from `0xE` to `0x0`, there were a transition from `0xE` back to `0x2` at the 9th rising edge? Then, only two of the four bits go from 1 to 0, and the output vector should become:

> `0xC` or `0b1100`.

Comment: Then what about the zoomed-in example waveforms of `in[1]` and `out[1]`? The `out[1]` goes high in the next cycle after a 1-to-0 transition in `in[1]`. It's still unclear to me.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Yes, `out[1]` goes high one cycle after `in[1]` goes from high to low. `in[1]` going high a second time that same cycle has no effect since the edge for that bit has already been captured.

Comment: My bad. I checked the waveforms again and now I got it. For some reason I though serial, not parallel. So it checks wire-by-wire, not the entire word representation.